# How can I create vertical bars showing a field extension?

Tags: diagrams

Specifically, I would like to create something like this:

[image]

Comment: I've tried the array environment, but it doesn't look so great.  Looking into tikz-cd.

Comment: You can be thankful by selecting and upvoting for an answer. ;)

Answer (score 8):

You can do that either with `pst-node`, or with `tikz-cd`. For the pstricks code, you must launch pdflatex with the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX) or `--shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
 \usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

 \[ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15, arrowsize=2pt 2, linewidth=0.5pt, nodesep=3pt, rowsep=0.9cm, colsep = 1.1cm, dash=3pt 2pt, shortput =nab, labelsep=2pt}
 \everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
 \begin{psmatrix}
 F(\beta) & F'(\beta') \\%
 F & F'
 %%%
\psset{nodesepB=2pt}
 \ncline[linestyle=dashed ]{1,1}{1,2}^{\widehat{\mathstrut\sigma}} \ncline{2,1}{2,2}^{\sigma}
 \psset{arrows=-}
 \ncline{1,1}{2,1}
 \ncline{1,2}{2,2}
 \end{psmatrix}
 \]

\[ \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2.5em, row sep=2.5em]
 F(\beta) \arrow[dashrightarrow, end anchor={[xshift=3pt]}]{r}{\widehat{\mathstrut\sigma}} \arrow[dash]{d}{} & F'(\beta') \arrow[dash]{d}{} \\%
F\arrow[end anchor={[xshift=2pt]}]{r}{\sigma}& F
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Shorter way with `tikz-cd`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1cm]
F(\beta) \arrow [d,-] \arrow[r,dashed,->,"\hat{\sigma}"] & F'(\beta')\arrow [d,-] \\
F \arrow[r,"\sigma"',below]&  F
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure about `\widehat{\mathstrut\sigma}`; I'd go with `\hat{\sigma}`.

Comment: @egreg Yes. I have changed it.

Comment: The image in the O.P.'s post seems to have something like a math strut, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0,0) {$F(\beta)$};
    \node (B) at (2,0) {$F'(\beta')$};
    \node (C) at (0,-2) {$F$};
    \node (D) at (2,-2) {$F'$};
    \draw[->,dashed] (A) -- (B) node[midway,above] {$\hat{\sigma}$};
    \draw[->] (C) -- (D) node[midway,below] {$\sigma$};
    \draw (A) -- (C);
    \draw (B) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```